# Switch to built-in microphone

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I have an Lenovo z50. The 3.5mm jack is a double use headphones/microphone.
The jack is broken and keeps detecting input. I've fixed my audio, but the computer still thinks that there's a microphone input (at least I think that's what's happening). How can I activate my built in microphone again?

Comment: Use the audio device manager? This allows you to choose speakers / microphones.

Comment: I can't seem to find it, I have only one microphone show up under my recording devices. Conexant has a smartaudio application, but can't seem to find it there either.

Comment: Does it show up in device manager?

Comment: It shows one microphone. 

https://i.gyazo.com/20ddbc89fbe2813e880d76c72bea915e.png

It's in dutch, but info on connection says  rightpanel 3.5 mm-plug
Since then I assumed it was thinking that there's a microphone plugged in

Answer (score 1):

In the lower bottom right of windows, right click on the *speaker* and choose *Recording Devices*, this shows you a list of input devices.

(Note: On each device you will see a little volume level as sound is heard)

Next right click in the list box (either on an item or in the empty space) and choose to be **ON** for:

- Show Disabled Devises
- Show Disconnected Devices

Now disable everything in this list except your built-in microphone.

Finally select your built-in microphone and click on *properties* and:

- In the ***Levels*** *tab* ensure it's not muted and set to 100%
- In the ***Listen*** *tab* ensure the:

  - "*Listen to this device*" is **off**,
  - *"Default Playback Device"* is **selected**
  - *"Continue running when on battery power"* is **selected**

Here is a screen shot of how it should look to function correctly:

[image: Windows 10 microphone settings to work for Cortana and speech recognition]
Now you can chat with Cortana ;-)

*P.S. a tip if you play with any sound Input or Output settings, don't trust the "Apply" button, instead do "OK" to close all windows to see if all is well. This is because sound devices drivers often have issues with the Immediate Mode to apply settings straight away*